# QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread error

Tags: qt, qml, qthread

i am getting QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread from this snippet and it's blocking my application and freezing the UI. I am kind of new to threading in QT.

```
   void ReportModel::myslot(){
        moveToThread(&thread);
        connect(&thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(exportProg()));
        thread.start();
    }
```

in **exportProg()** i am making a csv file in pendrive.

Comment: Does your `exportProg()` slot contain any code that interacts with previously-defined `QTimer`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `ReportModel` is likely a class used from the GUI thread, this won't work and is a bad idea. `this->moveToThread(...)` is usually a bad code smell unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Why are you moving the model to a thread in a slot? Shouldn't it be in a thread from the very beginning? Why are you connecting slots to the `started` signal? The idiom for job submittal to the current object thread's event loop can be `QTimer::singleShot(0, ...)` or `QMetaObject::invoke`, and that works without any dependency on a thread starting at that very moment. Most likely, `exportProg` should be a threadsafe method that can be submitted for asynchronous execution via `QtConcurrent::run`.

Comment: I have to move that model inside the thread because I am writing CSV files in the pen drive and it takes few seconds but while this operation happens it freezes the UI and it becomes unresponsive.exportProg has to be an asynchronous method for execution via QtConcurrent:: run.

Comment: It has to be a thread-safe method no matter how you run it, if you run it on a different thread. `moveToThread` isn't some magical threading fix. It doesn't make thread-unsafe methods become thread-safe.